# Production network calls stats

Tags: android, ios, mobile, monitoring, instrumentation

I'd like to get stats, like execution time, error codes, frequency, about all network calls being executed in production Android app and monitor them.

In past there was a great developer platform for it, [Pulse.io](http://pulse.io/), but it has been acquired by Google in May 2015.

How to easily get and monitor all production stats nowadays?